# Is there a way to eagerly resolve all components registered with Windsor IoC container?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have C# application where I register a few dozen interfaces with their implementation classes in the Windsor container. All these implementation classes are resolved as singletons by Windsor. The question is can I somehow make Windsor manually resolve all these stuff and wire them to create a object graph? Rather than lazy resolving that Windsor does by default when some component is request, I need to resolve them all at once for some debugging and testing purposes. Ideally I'd like to get the array of instances for all registered types. Is this possible?

Comment: AFAIK they aren't deferred... the graph is built as required on the first request from the container (most containers are like this I'm pretty sure). I'm not sure I get what you mean by "array of instances for all registered types". Can you elaborate?

Comment: So what I need is to ask Windsor container to resolve all registered interfaces instead of lazy resolving that happens when needed (eg. in my project that happens when HTTP request is received by WebAPI app). If possible I'd like to somehow get a list (or array) of all objects that were resolved and instantiated when I explicitly ask Windsor to do the resolving.

Answer (score 1):

The dependency graph is available through the `GraphNodes` property. Here's a simple demonstration:

```
[Test]
public void Get1()
{
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Register(Component.For<SomeClass>().LifestyleSingleton());
    container.Register(Component.For<Dependency>().LifestyleSingleton());

    var graphNodes = container.Kernel.GraphNodes;

    Assert.That(graphNodes.Length, Is.EqualTo(2));
    Assert.That(graphNodes[0].Dependents[0].ToString(), Is.EqualTo(typeof(Dependency).Name));
    Assert.That(graphNodes[1].Dependents.Length, Is.EqualTo(0));
}
```

You should easily be able to establish which types are "root" types by filtering out any types that are a dependency ...

---

**UPDATE**

One of the ways to create an instance from a `GraphNode` is to cast the `GraphNode` to `Castle.Core.ComponentModel`

```
[Test]
public void Resolve1()
{
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Register(Component.For<SomeClass>().LifestyleSingleton());
    container.Register(Component.For<Dependency>().LifestyleSingleton());

    var graphNodes = container.Kernel.GraphNodes;

    var name = (graphNodes[0] as ComponentModel).ComponentName.ToString();
    var type = Type.GetType(name);
    dynamic instance1 = container.Resolve(type);
    Assert.That(instance1, Is.Not.Null);
}
```

Comment: So when I find all root GraphNode how can I ask container to resolve them? How can I get type of class/interface that is described by some GraphNode object?

Comment: @matori82 please see my update for a potential solution

Answer (score 0):

Usually for debugging and testing the container you may use the [component handler](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Handlers.ashx) instead of resolving the component itself.

Said so, Simon is right: when you Resolve a component, windsor creates the real instance and all its dependencies. Nothing is "deferred" unless you mean "late dependency" achived through a (typed) factory, but that's somenthing else...

Answer (score 0):

The solution that uses ComponentName doesn't work. ComponentModel.Services should be used instead. Tested with version 3.3

```
        container.Kernel.GraphNodes
            .Cast<ComponentModel>()
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(component =>
            {
                component.Services
                    .ToList()
                    .ForEach(type =>
                    {
                        var instance = container.Resolve(type);
                        Assert.IsNotNull(instance);
                    });
            });
```